# Shopify: how to show a personal product collection?

Tags: themes, shopify, liquid

I want to show a collection to a logged in customer. This collection of products will be like a (limited/static) wishlist -- and it will belong to the specific customer. Assume I have the collection already. How would I display this collection for the customer who owns it? The customer will have to be logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. Every customer has an ID unique to them. So name your customer's collection after their ID. Put whatever you want in there. When they visit the store and that collection, use Liquid to ensure they are logged in, and that the current customer's ID matches the handle of the collection, which is also their ID.

I once built a very powerful App using this pattern that was essentially a super nice wishlist/curated collection for a merchant to offer his customers. That pattern works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When customers can have multiple personal collections, what would be the best approach in your experience? Using the customer ID as part of the collection handle or using metafields?

Comment: make it up. If you created a unique code for each collection belonging to a customer, and you used customer.tags or metafields, you could do the same thing to validate them.

Comment: I did it with metafields and it works well (in testing). Now deciding if the fields should be strings or integers. If strings, I might be able to put multiple IDs in each field for flexibility (or do other things I haven't thought of yet). But integers keeps it cleaner. Your thoughts?

Comment: Use ONE metafield, and yes, combine them into one structure. Liquid offers join and split on strings. Skip using many metafields for integers and looping. A string can be JSON too, useful perhaps for the front-end Javascript.